# Partition #3 contains a ext4 signature

Tags: filesystems, fdisk, signature

When i use fdisk to create a new partition i get an error which says

```
Partition #3 contains a ext4 signature

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o:
```

This error is not a problem but i am wondering why this error even comes up when the partition has not even been created with a filesystem.

While creating a partition i only had two partitions which were #1 and #2, there was no third partition at all. So how is there already a signature of a ext4 filesystem on the partition?

Comment: Partitions get a signature so the type is known. A small byte sequence is written to distinguish for example Linux filesystems (ext*) from swap. This doesn't mean anything but helps avoiding errors like using LUKS to encrypt the wrong partition, e.g. an EFI system partition or to write an ext-filesystem to a swap partition. Did you check initial layout with `fdisk -l`? Is it a used harddisk/ storage? Maybe restore the partition table and peek into the files showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check (non-interactively) with "-l": `fdisk -l /dev/sda`? Or just `fdisk -l`? To get an overwiev.

This gives me:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  83888127  83886080   40G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2   83888128 109053951  25165824   12G Linux root (x86-64)
/dev/sda3  109053952 142608383  33554432   16G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  276826112 411043839 134217728   64G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  411043840 415238143   4194304    2G EFI System
/dev/sda16 142609000 166609000  24000001 11.5G Linux root (x86-64)

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

As you can see, the end of sda3 is the beginning of sda16 (end / start sectors). This happended because I "named" my fourth partition "16" and not "4". Now I have that warning or hint. (I also left some holes...)

So "sda16", would that be #4 (physical) or #6 (numeric sort, like output of fdisk) or #16 (number I gave to that partition) in your fdisk? busybox or util-linux?

---

ADDED:

but then it is no error (never was), just a confusing comfirmation by fdisk? With my fdisk I have never seen this, but it has `--wipe` or `-w` option which handles exactly that: depending on interactive or not, AUTO, NEVER or ALWAYS wipe (says manpage).

I just checked my partitions with `wipefs`: sda1 to sda4 have one line, sda5 has 3 lines, sda16 has no line. I don't understand why. If you end up with a partition #3 after answering that question Y or N, it should be OK.

The question could mean: On this newly created #3, keep or wipe the signature?

`fdisk -V` gives me: "fdisk from util-linux 2.34"

Comment: i have tried this but my partition table only contains two enteries which are /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2. When i create a new /dev/sda3 partition this error i mentioned in my question appears. i have not named it incorrectly as you have i have named it normally.

Comment: I added a part to my answer...is there more confusion than error in this all?